# How to find height of a building from its changing shadow?

Tags: angle

The shadow of a building increased by 10 meters when the angle of elevation of the sun decreased by 10 degrees from 70 degrees to 60 degrees.

Calculate the height of the building.

I tried to construct a diagram, but was unable to make one which had both the angles of elevation and height of the building. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $h$ be the height of the building and $L$ the length of the shadow. Then, we have

$$h=L\tan 60,\>\>\>\>\>h=L'\tan70$$

and

$$\frac{h}{\tan60}-\frac{h}{\tan70} = L - L' = 10$$

Thus, the height of the building is given by,

$$h = \frac{10}{\frac{1}{\tan60}-\frac{1}{\tan70}}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. How did you get 10/(1/sin60 etc)? I got h = 10 * (sin70*sin60)/(sin70-sin60), how would I change that into the form you have written?